# spring eventListener with external condition

Tags: spring, event-handling

I need a flexible filters for `FooEvents` for multiple EventListeners all over my code.
I can use @EventListener(condition="event.enabled"), but my filters require many attributes of fooEvent to be analysed.

I was hoping that I could use a Predicate-Bean from my Application Context:

```
@Component
public class FooPredicate implements Predicate<FooEvent> {
   public boolean test(FooEvent event) {...}
}

...

@EventListener(condition="${fooPredicate.test(event)}")
public void handle(FooEvent event) { ... }
```

But I get:

```
org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1011E: 
   Method call: Attempted to call method 
   test(org.springframework.context.PayloadApplicationEvent) on null 
   context object
```

Is it possible to use external, complex conditions for EventListerns? Or at least to define global listeners with complex conditions and inherit their behavior without repeating the full conditions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're using the wrong definition, as `fooPredicate` is a spring bean you need to use '@' instead of '#' to resolve it as a bean. see [10.5.13 Bean references](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-bean-references)

```
@EventListener(condition="@fooPredicate.test(#event)")
public void handle(FooEvent event) {
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: Thanks again for this answer, I always come back to this to look up the semantic.  Additional question: is it possible to reference a "test" method on the same bean as the "handle" method without referencing the bean by its full name? Something like @this or @self?