# spring eventlistener with annotation based condition

Tags: spring, event-handling

This is somehow a follow up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123796/spring-eventlistener-with-external-condition).

Being able to filter events based on a bean-predicate:

```
 @EventListener(condition="@mypredicate.test(#event))
```

I wonder if I can achieve the following:

```
 @MyCondition(maxValue=5)
 @EventListener(condition="@myAnnotationAwarePredicate.test(#event))
```

So myAnnotationAwarePredicate uses the filter defined in the annotation.

Background: I am author of a library (camunda-bpm-reactor) where I use

```
 @CamundaSelector(event="create", process="myProcess")
```

to filter events sent to a topic on the projectreactor eventBus.

I have to get rid of the eventBus, cause it's discontinued, but still want the declaritive, non repeating filter style and keep backwar compatibility ....