# RabbitListener annotation queue name by ConfigurationProperties

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I have configured my rabbit properties via application.yaml and spring configurationProperties.
Thus, when I configure exchanges, queues and bindings, I can use the getters of my properties

```
@Bean Binding binding(Queue queue, TopicExchange exchange) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange).with(properties.getQueue());
}

@Bean Queue queue() {
    return new Queue(properties.getQueue(), true);
}

@Bean TopicExchange exchange() {
    return new TopicExchange(properties.getExchange());
}
```

However, when I configure a @RabbitListener to log the messages on from the queue, I have to use the full properties name like

```
 @RabbitListener(queues = "${some.long.path.to.the.queue.name}") 
 public void onMessage(
            final Message message, final Channel channel) throws Exception {
       log.info("receiving message: {}#{}", message, channel);
    }
```

I want to avoid this error prone hard coded String and refer to the configurationProperties bean like:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${properties.getQueue()}")
```

I had a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123796/spring-eventlistener-with-external-condition) once with @EventListener where using a bean reference "@bean.method()" helped, but it does not work here, the bean expression is just interpreted as queue name, which fails because a queue namde "@bean...." does not exist.

Is it possible to use ConfigurationProperty-Beans for RabbitListener queue configuration?

Comment: The spring doc says: "If the evaluation context has been configured with a bean resolver it is possible to lookup beans from an expression using the (@) symbol."  So I guess thats not the case for Rabbit ...

Answer (score 8):

Something like this worked for me where I just used the Bean and SpEL.

```
@Autowired
Queue queue;

@RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue.getName()}")
```

Comment: can we apply this for multiple queues? I mean is SpEL useful for listening multiple queues with RabbitListener? I couldn't see any example for it.

Comment: This also works @RabbitListener(queues = "#{queue}")

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to accomplish what we both desired to do by taking what @David Diehl suggested, using the bean and SpEL; however, using MyRabbitProperties itself instead. I removed the @EnableConfigurationProperties(MyRabbitProperties.class) in the config class, and registered the bean the standard way:

```
@Configuration
//@EnableConfigurationProperties(RabbitProperties.class)
@EnableRabbit
public class RabbitConfig {
  //private final MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties;

  //@Autowired
  //public RabbitConfig(MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties) {
    //this.myRabbitProperties = myRabbitProperties;
  //}      

  @Bean 
  public TopicExchange myExchange(MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties) {
    return new TopicExchange(myRabbitProperties.getExchange());
  }

  @Bean
  public Queue myQueueBean(MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties) {
    return new Queue(myRabbitProperties.getQueue(), true);
  }

  @Bean 
  public Binding binding(Queue myQueueBean, TopicExchange myExchange, MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties) {
    return BindingBuilder.bind(myQueueBean).to(myExchange).with(myRabbitProperties.getRoutingKey());
  }

  @Bean
  public MyRabbitProperties myRabbitProperties() {
    return new MyRabbitProperties();
  }
}
```

From there, you can access the get method for that field:

```
@Component
public class RabbitQueueListenerClass {

  @RabbitListener(queues = "#{myRabbitProperties.getQueue()}") 
  public void processMessage(Message message) {

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "#{myQueue.name}")
```

Answer (score 0):

Listener:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = "${queueName}")
```

application.properties:

```
queueName=myQueue
```